# Why is my console.log(variable) showing two differently values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, browser, console

[image]I'm doing a alg. to set the distance between two rgb collors, but instead it is returning me wrong values, why?

```
  let tests = [[128, 0, 0], [170, 110, 40], [128, 128, 0], [0, 128, 128], [0, 0, 128],
    [0, 0, 0], [230, 25, 75], [245, 130, 48], [255, 225, 25], [210, 245, 60], [60, 180, 75],
    [70, 240, 240], [0, 130, 200], [145, 30, 180], [240, 50, 230], [128, 128, 128], [250, 190, 190],
    [255, 215, 180], [255, 250, 200], [170, 255, 195], [230, 190, 255], [255, 255, 255]]
  let corFinal = [0, 0, 0]
  let coresFinais = []
  let menorDist = 256
  getPaletteFromURL(this.imageTest, 8, 1).then((response) => {
    console.log('array de cores', response)
    response.forEach((color) => {
      tests.forEach((test) => {
        let dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(test[0] - color[0], 2) + Math.pow(test[1] - color[1], 2) + Math.pow(test[2] - color[2], 2))
        if (dist < menorDist) {
          menorDist = dist
          corFinal[0] = test[0]
          corFinal[1] = test[1]
          corFinal[2] = test[2]
          console.log(corFinal)
        }
      })
      console.log(corFinal)
      menorDist = 256
      coresFinais.push(corFinal)
    })
    console.log('array final', coresFinais)
  })
```

Response is an array of arrays in the same style of 'tests'

Running a console.log(test[0]) does show the right value.
The console.log(corFinal) does show TWO VALUES

Comment: The same array `corFinal` is being updated and pushed to `coresFinais` in every loop. Declare it inside the `forEach`

Comment: Actually, i want to take just the minor distance. So it's after the loop

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error was that i was updating array field by field (Which i don't know why was returning wrong values).

So i changed to:

```
corFinal = test
```

Then code worked.

Comment: It is not returning wrong values. Every index of `coresFinais` is pointing to the same `corFinal` reference. If you update it as you are doing with `corFinal[0] = `, it will update all the indexes of the `coresFinais` array. This answer will work because you are reassigning the `corFinal`. Now it won't have reference to the original array any more